# Watir finds element by xpath, but not by id or class

Tags: ruby, firefox, watir, watir-webdriver, ruby-watir

I can find an element using its XPath, but not using its ID, class, or text. I don't want to use XPath because I know it will break easily.

This is what it looks like:

```
$browser.div(:xpath => "/html/body/nav/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div").present?
$browser.div(:xpath => "/html/body/nav/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div").click
```

It returns true and clicks on the element.

Following the path, I find the element, then try use its ID, like:

```
$browser.div(:id => "PaymentSelector").present?
$browser.div(:id => "PaymentSelector").click
```

It returns false and times out trying to click. The same happens with text or class.

The element is not inside a frame or iframe.

Why would this happen and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you try to give a minimal, reproducible example? This could be caused by anything from a timing issue to a typo, and I have no way of knowing.

Comment: I don't really know how to give a reproducible example. But using the xpath, i can find and click on it. Then, using the same xpath, i get the id and text from it, so i'm 100% sure the id is correct. But then i substitute the one getting by xpath, for $browser.div(:id => "PaymentSelector").present?. and then, it does not find it. Any reason i should tell the parents of this div?

Comment: OK, a simpler explanation:
    $browser.div(:xpath => "/html/body/nav/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div").present?
returns true.

 $browser.div(:xpath => "/html/body/nav/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div[3]/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div/div").id

Returns: PaymentSelector

$browser.div(:id => "PaymentSelector").present?
Returns: false

Comment: It sounds like you might have multiple elements on the page with the same id. What is the output if you do a `$browser.divs(:id => "PaymentSelector").count`?

Comment: Well, it returned 5.
But why does it say False for .present? if there are 5 of this.
Also tried using] .first.click, times out

Comment: Unless you tell Watir otherwise, it will interact with the first match. In this case, the first match is not visible and not likely the one you are interested in. You need to make your locator more specific, but without the HTML of your page, it's difficult to give you options.

Comment: I will get the HTML. In the meantime, is there a way to tell watir to click on 2nd or 3rd element? Thank you very much!

Comment: Ok, i checked the ones that are visible, there are 1 of them, then i used [2].click, and it worked. Thanks for the help, i was stuck on it for many hours. I will check with the developer why we have all those elements.

Comment: When parsing XML or HTML, don't use a long, explicit, selector to your desired node. Instead, find way-points and unique nodes you can use to navigate. Sometimes we have to find something near what we are trying to access, and then use relative motion to get there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the problem is that there are multiple elements with the same id. This can be seen by calling:

```
$browser.divs(:id => "PaymentSelector").count
#=> 5
```

Watir returns the first matching element, which in this case, happens to be a hidden element. It is not the one that a user is interested in. You need to craft a more specific locator so that the right element is returned.

One option is to specify the `:index` since you now know it is the second one:

```
$browser.div(:id => "PaymentSelector", :index => 2).click
```

However, it will likely be more robust to just find the first visible one by using the `:visible` locator:

```
$browser.div(:id => "PaymentSelector", :visible => true).click
```

Comment: Note, for the DOM to have multiple elements with the same ID (unless they are inside different frames) is invalid HTML.    If it was me I would personally write up a bug against that saying that the HTML violates standards by having more than a single element with a given ID value.

Comment: WC3 Standards for [ID values](https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#adef-id)